# WPF custom button - binding Dynamic and Static Resources

Tags: wpf, binding

i would like create my button with style (StaticResources) and icon (DynamicResources). I dont know, how to binding resources. StaticResource can i binding as object.
This is my code:

```
<Button x:Class="Spd.Client.View.Controls.IconButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{Binding ButtonStyle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Icon, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="10" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
   public partial class IconButton : Button, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _text;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text)); }
        }

        private object _style;

        public object ButtonStyle
        {
            get { return _style; }
            set { _style = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Style));}
        }

        public ??? Icon //which datatype?
        {
            get { }
            set
            {

            }
        }

        public IconButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Using:

```
    <controls1:IconButton Text="Click me!" ButtonStyle="{StaticResource DangerButton}" 
                          Icon="{DynamicResource appbar_user}"></controls1:IconButton>
```

Comment: Could you show us what is your Icon? and if you use it as a `StaticResource` does it work?

Comment: Just go for a simple template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Don't think too complecate.

```
<Button Style={StaticResource ButtonStyle} Content={Binding Icon}>
```

Regards

Steffen

Comment: Thanks, but its not what i found. Style attribute is correct, but Icon dont. My motivation is writing only Icon={DynamicResource appbar_user} without  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">...</Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>